# How charge is explained, in context of bonding?

Tags: electric-fields, charge, atomic-physics, orbitals

In ionic compounds, like NaCl, Cl gains negative charge due to addition of electrons. In covalent compounds, like Cl2, sharing of electrons occurs. Here too, Cl atom has got an extra electron in its orbitals. But it is shared. How come sharing of electrons vanish the charge that Cl must have gained?

I thought  that Cl atom experience only half the charge of electron as it is shared, so there is no excess charge gained, remaining neutral. But it doesn't convince me. How the idea of charge is exhibited here?

So my question is, Cl atom gets an electron shared by another Cl atom. But why its charge is neutral (formal charge of Cl in Cl2 is 0)?

Answer (score 2):

Electrons, atoms, molecules are all in the realm of quantum mechanics. Quantum mechanics is a probabilistic theory, which means there are no orbits for electrons for their charge to be shared , but orbitals: probability of the electron ( with its charge) to be at a particular (x,y,z) at time t. To get an idea , these are the orbitals of the [hydrogen atom:](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Chemical/eleorb.html)

[image: horb]

In an H2 molecule there will be a probability of overlaps, and this probability is high since the H2 molecule exists. In classical terms the two nuclei are playing ball with their electrons, so the total molecule is neutral. In the quantum  mechanical true level, there are regions in space where the electrons exist and regions where their probability to be there is very small. In those regions the charge of the nuclei is not masked and a positive charge could be measured. See these [molecular orbitals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_orbital):

[image: molorb]

Negative charge is high in space where there are electron orbitals, and positive in the empty spaces, in classical terms, allowing like LEGO blocks for various molecules to bond , but one should always keep quantum mechanics  in mind about probabilities of the electrons being in a given location.

(QM is a necessary frame, because without it there would be no atoms or molecules, as in classical electrodynamics the electrons  would  spiral down to the nucleus and neutralize it.)

Answer (score 2):

First up: the separation of compounds into "purely ionic" and "purely covalent" is an artificial one. Most molecules fall somewhere in between: there will be some form of covalent bonding, but with an asymmetric sharing of the total charge. "Purely covalent" bonds are indeed possible in [homonuclear molecules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homonuclear_molecule), simply because of symmetry, but "purely ionic" compounds are somewhat of a fiction: you can get very close to it, if the two atoms have a huge disparity in [electronegativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronegativity), but ultimately all ionic compounds just have highly asymmetric covalent bonds.

With that in mind, in *every* chemical bond, the electric charge is not concentrated into a single location. Instead, it forms a diffuse "cloud" of charge that's spread over space, including both atoms as well as the region in between.

As an example, here is a contour map of the electron density in the asymmetric covalent compound HCl:

[image]

<sup>[Image source](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/236579151_Dipole_Moment_Surfaces_of_the_CH_4_X_CH_3_HX_X_F_Cl_Reactions_from_Atomic_Dipole_Moment_Surfaces_and_the_Origins_of_the_Sharp_Extrema_of_the_Dipole_Moments_near_the_Transition_States): [*J. Phys. Chem. A* **117**, 7468 (2013)](https://doi.org/10.1021/jp401555h)</sup>

As you can see, the electrons are localized all over the molecule, and it is not easy to separate the charge density to assign what part of it belongs to the hydrogen and what part belongs to the chlorine. The response to this difficulty is the concept of [partial charge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_charge), which encapsulates a relatively wide array of ways to try to capture this charge imbalance, and which (thankfully) generally agree with each other.

Basically, we try to set up some form of imaginary separation between the two atoms, and count up the total charge on either side of the separation (which need not be an integer number of electron charges!). This depends on the details of what imaginary separation we choose, so it is always a bit of a fudgy concept and it needs to be handled with care, but there's still an objective reality behind it.

In a symmetric molecule such as Cl$_2$, the electron density is symmetric between the two chlorine atoms, and it shows a clear additional concentration in the region between the two. If we divide space, then each atom gets exactly half of the total charge (and thus a net charge of zero) because, when doing the division, we take the shared pair and assign half of the charge there to each of the atoms.

Comment: While dividing the space each atom gets exactly half of total charge, but while bonding there is excess of charge for each, right? So how net charge is 0?

Answer (score 1):

Consider sharing as a sort of polarization (deformation) of a neutal atom without sharing.

Answer (score -1):

You have one stone. Your friend has one stone. Your friend and you share your stones. You have two shared stones. Your friend has two shared stones. You have one stone. Your friend has one stone.